# for which odd number n does 503 divide $n^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is already mentioned in the title: For which odd number n does 503 divide $n^2+1$

$503\cdot q=n^2+1$

Answer (score 4):

$503$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$ hence there is no integer $n$ such that $503$ divides $n^2+1$

Let $p=4k+3$ And assume that there is some integer $n$ such that $n^2\equiv -1 \mod p$ then we have $n^{p-1}\equiv (n^2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (-1)^{2k+1}\equiv -1 \mod p$

now using [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we have $n^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: How can you conclude that?

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is it (mod 4)?

Comment: @NickPodowalski note that **every** square number is either $0$ or $1$ mod 4.  So, $n^2+1$ is always either $1$ or $2$ mod 4.

Comment: @Igor you have made some mistake because it's not possible, [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=94907047%5E2+%2B+1+mod+503)

Comment: Checked this in Excel :) All matches. Do you see my error?

Comment: @Igor The calculation in excel are not exact :$$94907047^2 + 1 =2+503\cdot 17907251630736$$

Comment: Yep, you're right. I guess, it's a double overfloat or something like that... Thanks!